# Can a Union be self-referenced in C?

Tags: c, unions

I have been asked in an interview "Can a Union be self-referenced?"

I know that `struct` can  self-reference, but I'm really confused about `union`. I've read in one text book that union can self-reference, but it didn't say anything more on the subject.

Can anyone confirm whether a `union` *is* or *is not* able to be self-referenced?

Answer (score 4):

sure it can, really the same way as `struct`:

```
union toto {
  union toto* a;
  unsigned b;
};
```

as soon as the tag identifier `toto` is known to be a `union` type `union toto*` is a pointer to an incomplete type.

Difficult to figure out that this knowledge will serve you for something else than an interview, though.

Comment: the reason why i am interested in this question is different text book have different to say abou this thing

Comment: http://www.infibeam.com/Books/info/bala-subramaniam/cracking-interview-jumpstart-your-career-with-confidence/9780070600522.html .This very much book have to say Union can't be self-referenced

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar : does the book give an explanation for that? GCC accepts it and I didn't find something about it in a draft of the C standard.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar, @evnu, probably we speak of two different things here. `union` and `struct` can't be recursive in that they can't contain a member that is exactly the same `union` or `struct`. It only can contain pointers to its own type. But in that sense `union` or `struct` is of no difference. Pointers to any `union` or `struct` type who's declaration is not finished are "pointers to an incomplete type". This is completely legal in C and used all allong.